# How to establish a communication between FPGA and CPU, in real-time?

Tags: fpga, verilog, uart, cpu, java

I am working on a project that involves FPGA and CPU communication(in real-time - i.e, CPU and FPGA should function together).

I have already designed and tested the UART communication protocol on FPGA using Hterm terminal (Its working splendidly). But, to finalize this, I should write a C++ or Java program on the CPU.

I tried using Java RxTx library for the same. But, no data is being sent to the FPGA, or received from the FPGA.

Can anyone here suggest the suitable language and tool for establishing a communication between FPGA and CPU using a Serial communication link(UART / RS-232).

PS::  Any links will be highly helpful.

Comment: If your UART core on the FPGA works, then *anything*. Literally any piece of software, library, code, etc. design for writing to serial points.

Comment: Can you please provide any link for the same... If you know any..

Comment: I tried using RxTx Java API. But I don't think I am doing it correctly

Comment: Any link would be highly appreciated. As a reference. The one used was for Arduino, but I would guess similar thing for FPGA. Any additional information would be useful..

Comment: PC serial support generally sucks. I don't know why. Labview used to do a good job of supporting it. You can look into it if it meets your purposes.

Comment: https://github.com/wjwwood/serial? Processing? Google is your friend.

Comment: When you say 'project that involves FPGA and CPU communication' Do you mean a CPU and FPGA on the same PCB, or do you mean a host PC (e.g. running Windows, Linux etc.) and the FPGA, or something else? BTW - why did you choose to use asynchronous communications?

Comment: Thank you all for your comments... @gbulmer. By CPU I mean your normal CPU. x86 Intel host PC running Windows/Linux...

Comment: @gbulmer .. Cz data transmission is not regular.

Comment: So a real time OS talking to an FPGA.  Because other wise you should just memory map the FPGA and be done with it.  If you are not going to take a screwdriver to the PC then you really only have USB and Ethernet.  And you can put just about anything inside of those pipes.

Comment: " But, no data is being sent to the FPGA, or received from the FPGA." Sounds like you have a classic in-person debugging problem.  While  I wouldn't personally opt for the software you chose, you should at the least be able to identify the problem.  Just jumping to shop for a different solution each time there is a difficulty is not a way to get anything done - you need to develop the ability to to take something that *should* work and make it do so.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively simple C program to handle serial communication from a host to a microcontroller (originally Arduino) was published many years ago by [TodBot](https://todbot.com/blog/2006/12/06/arduino-serial-c-code-to-talk-to-arduino/)

The C source is on [github](https://github.com/todbot/arduino-serial)

I've used an older version. It has a few more options now, but is still short enough to be relatively understandable. It is written in C, so it should compile on most systems with a POSIX-like compiler and basic library.

The two main files of source code, arduino-serial.c and arduino-serial-lib.c are about 350 lines of straightforward C. Ignore arduino-serial-server.c, it's irrelevant.

Most (all) modern operating systems are written in C/C++. C/C++ works well for this sort of command-line task. Many of the Operating System APIs are documented for use directly from C/C++. So there isn't much extra to cause complexity, and questions posed in C should be easiest to get answered. C/C++ aren't the easiest to use or prettiest languages, but they are well understood, have lots of users and source code, and are stable. C is significantly simpler than C++, so learning and using C will be simpler for this sort of task.

You might not have access to a PC with serial/RS232. Get a USB-UART cable, and use that. I use genuine FTDI USB-UARTs, and have never had problems. Host Operating systems will already have drivers for USB-UARTs, so there should be no need to install any drivers if you use a well known product. That C program was designed to use an FTDI USB-UART, but I imagine it'll work correctly across most products because it uses a small subset of serial I/O facilities.